# VBA Application.InputBox Validation. Selection only within certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create an input box for users to select a cell, and the macro will filter some external data by the users selection.

I want to add validation to the selection so users can only select a cell with a value of "TRUE" and only within a certain range e.g column Range("J4:J100")

Code so far:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("J4:J100")

Dim criteria1 As Range
Set criteria1 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

Dim criteria2 As String
criteria2 = criteria1.Offset(0, -9)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Reference_log")

ws.Select

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastColumn As Long 'Find the last non-blank cell in row 2
LastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Rng1 = Cells(2, 8)
Set Rng2 = Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)



ActiveSheet.Range(Rng1, Rng2).AutoFilter Field:=2, criteria1:=Array("*" & criteria2 & "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Check the `Intersect`ion of the result of the inputbox and the range in question.